# Generating progress bar based on variable value

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I'm making a very simple text-based pet game, and I need a way for the pet's "food meter" to increase. The user can open a menu where they can select "FEED" by writing it out, and this needs to add 1 bar to the food meter.

I have every version of the food meter set up as separate variables, like this:

```
statfull = "[▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇]"
stat9 = "[▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇_]"
stat8 = "[▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇__]"
stat7 = "[▇▇▇▇▇▇▇___]"
stat6 = "[▇▇▇▇▇▇____]"
stat5 = "[▇▇▇▇▇_____]"
stat4 = "[▇▇▇▇______]"
stat3 = "[▇▇▇_______]"
stat2 = "[▇▇________]"
stat1 = "[▇_________]"
statempty = "[__________]"
```

If the food bar's variable currently prints stat7, how can I make it go up a level (in this case change to stat8) when the user inputs the word "FEED"? 
By which I mean:

```
currentFStat = stat7
print("Your food bar is at " + currentFStat)
```

Which would look like

Your food bar is at [▇▇▇▇▇▇▇___]

I want the player to be able to input "FEED" when prompted, and then have the program change the value of currentFStat to stat8 so that when it

```
print("Your food bar is at " + currentFStat)
```

the output would now be

Your food bar is at [▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇__]

The only way I can think of doing it is having an if statement for every possible state it could be at, and if it's that state, changing to the next, but that seems way too tedious and I'm sure there's an easier way I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead representing the food level of your pet with an integer variable:

```
foodlevel = 5 # for example
```

If user FEEDs your pet, increment `foodlevel`. Decrement otherwise.

Use `foodlevel` to create your health meter on the go:

```
>>> '▇' * foodlevel + '_' * (10 - foodlevel)
'▇▇▇▇▇_____'
```

I've assumed that 10 is "full", while 0 is "empty". You can modify this design as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much and this is a really intuitive way of doing it I hadn't thought of! I kind of have a further question that just popped up- is there any way for me to let the user type in the "FEED" command even unprompted? Like, at any time they want?

Comment: @nefeletor I don't think so, unless you have a dedicated input channel listening for user input all the time... [this might help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036732/python-accept-user-input-at-any-time) You're welcome.